# ¿Cómo agregar una columna de números consecutivos, agrupados por una variable en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo agregar una columna que registre consecutivamente el número de veces que se repite ID.
El resultado esperado, sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado intentando con el siguiente código, pero no sé como hacerlo considerando un group by. Probablemente, la solución sea otra.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) as VECES, * from dbo.TABLA1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te faltó la parte de `PARTITION BY`

> Divide el conjunto de resultados generado por la cláusula FROM en
> particiones a las que se aplica la función ROW_NUMBER.
> value_expression especifica la columna a partir de la cual se
> particiona el conjunto de resultados. Si no se especifica PARTITION
> BY, la función trata todas las filas del conjunto de resultados de la
> consulta como un único grupo.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC) as VECES, * from dbo.TABLA1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Muchas gracias.